# I want to add inline style to YII t(' ')

Tags: php, yii

I want to add style **' float:right '** for this text. I tried some way,but not works. How should i add inline css for this.

```
public function title()
{
    return $this->t('You have {amount} of credit', 
    array('{amount}' => m('payment')->format(wm()->get('payment.helper')->credit())),
    array('style'=>'float:right'));
}
```

Can you give me a hint, please?

Answer (score 2):

Yii translation function looks like this: [`Yii::t('category', 'message', \['params' => 'value'\])`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n). So you need `style` to be in your message to translate it.

```
Yii::t(
    'admin',
    'You have <span style="{style}">{amount}</span>',
    [
        '{style}' => 'color: red;',
        '{amount}' => 'Test',
    ]
);

-> <span style="color: red;">Test</span>
```

Comment: it's getting like this error  `Illegal offset type in isset or empty` @Justinas

Comment: @rokz92 I have no idea what code you use, because neither I nor you are using `isset` or `empty`. Check your code.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Justinas, (Great thanks for your example, it really works) but there one tiny mistake in your code:

```
'{style}' => 'color: red;'  // in this case style would not be applicable to a span
```

has to be so:

```
'style' => 'color: red;'
```

Tested on my case, works for sure.